# what is the latest version of ionic build 1.1.0 or 1.6.4

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed ionic using the following command:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

After navigating to node_modules/ionic folder on my local machine and opening the package.json file, it says that the version is 1.6.4

However the ionicframework.com website says the latest version is 
1.1.0 "xenon-xerus"

This is quiet confusing. Can someone clarify

Comment: are you sure? because, the right version is 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between the ionic CLI (version 1.6.4) and the ionic lib in your application project (version 1.1.0).

if you type `ionic -v` you'll get the version of the CLI (command line interface)

if you go into your project folder and type `ionic lib` you'll get the lib version.

Btw: You update the library with `ionic lib update`

Answer (score 0):

Latest version: 1.7.8

Run **npm install -g ionic to update**

check version ----

**ionic --version**

1.7.8

Answer (score 0):

run following command in terminal/cmd: **ionic info** that command will give you full details of ionic and Cordova installed in your pc and project.

And then you can use **npm install -g ionic** for install latest ionic build.